# How to remove hidden layers from result PDF using iText7

Tags: .net, pdf, ocr, itext7

I am using iText7. There are several source pdfs with a lot of layers. Some of them are hidden. I would like to create one result pdf where source pdfs go one by one. I use the following method to copy pages to result pdf:

`sourcePdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(pageFrom, pageTo, destinationPdfDocument);`

As a result of copying all hidden layers are visible (this is likely because OCProperties are missing in result pdf). But I would expect hidden layers are not visible in result pdf.
I found question (perhaps obsoleted one) related to such functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107848/itext-7-merge-pdf-layers-ocg-with-the-base-pdf). However don't see the way how we can remove OCG-related information from the catalog.

Could you please help with that? Is there in iText7 any ability to remove certain layer? Any ideas?